# Async function in React doesn't have access to this

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React with Apollo Client. When a user logs in I need to refetch the `USER` query so that I can decide where to redirect them based on what fields are present in their profile.

My code hangs at this line:

```
await this.props.USER.refetch();
```

I think this is because making the function async changes the context of `this`.

```
async login() {

  const result = await this.props.LoginMutation({
    variables: {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    },
  });

  const token = await result.data.authenticateUser.token;

  await this._saveUserData(token);

  // This is where the code hangs 
  await this.props.USER.refetch();


  // If no user profile pic has been set then redirect to the account page
  if (!this.props.USER.user.profilePic) {
    this.setState({
      redirect: '/account',
    });
  }

  // If no location is set redirect to the homepage
  if (!this.props.USER.user.location) {
    this.setState({
      redirect: '/',
    });
  }

  if (this.props.USER.user.location) {
    this.setState({
      redirect: `/${this.props.USER.user.location.machineName}`,
    });
  }

  this.setState({
    redirect: `/`,
  });
}
```

React dev tools shows me that `this.props.USER.refetch()` does exist:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not because of async that the function achieves a different context, but because functions in ES6 class need to be be bound explicitly. Make use of arrow function like

```
login = async () => {

  const result = await this.props.LoginMutation({
    variables: {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    },
  });

  const token = await result.data.authenticateUser.token;

  await this._saveUserData(token);

  // This is where the code hangs 
  await this.props.USER.refetch();


  // If no user profile pic has been set then redirect to the account page
  if (!this.props.USER.user.profilePic) {
    this.setState({
      redirect: '/account',
    });
  }

  // If no location is set redirect to the homepage
  if (!this.props.USER.user.location) {
    this.setState({
      redirect: '/',
    });
  }

  if (this.props.USER.user.location) {
    this.setState({
      redirect: `/${this.props.USER.user.location.machineName}`,
    });
  }

  this.setState({
    redirect: `/`,
  });
}
```

Comment: My code is still hanging in the same place. React dev tools shows me the function does exist (see update to my question) so could this be an Apollo specific issue not a Rect one?

Comment: Turns out it was an Apollo issue. I crated a new component which has its own page and refetched the queries in componentDidMount. Now its working.